# NTP: Use unprivileged ports

Tags: amazon-ec2, ntp

I have had some trouble with `ntdpate` on EC2, which was [solved by using the `-u` argument for unprivileged ports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487027/cant-run-ntpdate-on-ec2):

```
$ sudo ntpdate -u ntp.nasa.gov time-b.nist.gov
```

I know that `ntpd` is better than a periodic execution of `ntpdate` via cron, because it features [Frequency Discipline](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm), meaning that the calls to the internet will be less frequent as the drift fix is more accurate.

Therefore, I would like to run the NTP daemon (`sudo service ntp start`) with unprivileged ports. I have looked at the `man ntpd` but did not find any reference to that option.

Any idea how to make `ntpd` use unprivileged ports?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232722/ntpd-use-an-unrestricted-port-for-communication

Comment: @Adam is there something wrong with my answer? Initially you accepted the answer and then you withdrew the acceptance without explanation. It seems I have provided documentation that demonstrates that openntpd uses unprivileged ports by default. What more do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not run ntpd with unprivileged ports: http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/TroubleshootingNTP#Section_9.8.

However you can use openntpd which is a project from the OpenBSD folks. OpenNTPd does not require a privileged port for full time operation / clock discipline.

http://www.openntpd.org

**More information for the skeptics:**

I am including this since there seems to be some uncertainty that openntpd uses an unprivileged port. For starters looking through any of the presentations about the design considerations of openntpd you can see the developers do not list "sending from port below 1024" as one of the uses of privilege separation. This is how openntpd works, by default, in fact you can not configure openntpd to use  a privileged port if you wanted to.

More importantly you can see evidence for this behavior in many  posts about openntpd that show printouts from netstat or. [This launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/858493/comments/4)   lists the output of netstat when openntpd is running:

```
 netstat -atpun | grep ntp
 udp 0 0 myIP:57706 88.190.225.228:123 ESTABLISHED 32455/ntpd
 udp 0 0 myIP:46760 188.40.33.81:123 ESTABLISHED 32455/ntpd
 udp 0 0 myIP:33742 88.190.225.228:123 ESTABLISHED 32455/ntpd
 udp 0 0 myIP:34625 85.10.199.217:123 ESTABLISHED 32455/ntpd
```

See the client port for the established connections? It is above 1024.

Another [example from these instructions](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-install-openntpd-ntp-server-to-synchronize-system-clock-on-freebsd-for-better-security/) using freebsd provides the output of sockstat:

```
freebsd# sockstat -4 -p 123
USER COMMAND PID FD PROTO LOCAL ADDRESS FOREIGN ADDRESS
_ntp ntpd 31696 4 udp4 83.228.93.76:54555 212.70.148.15:123
_ntp ntpd 31696 6 udp4 83.228.93.76:56666 195.69.120.36:123
_ntp ntpd 31696 8 udp4 83.228.93.76:49976 217.75.140.188:123
```

See how the local address has a port above 1024?

One more [example of netstat](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?/archives/3-OpenNTPD-on-Linux.html) on linux with openntpd:

```
# netstat -u -p

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
udp        0      0 aquilonia:32771         skylar.fbagroup.co.:ntp ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:32772         gw.roaima.co.uk:ntp     ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:33050         ginny.provu.co.uk:ntp   ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:33051         cobra.first4it.co.u:ntp ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:33053         shrewd.pub.knigma.o:ntp ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:34275         cheddar.halon.org.u:ntp ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd           
udp        0      0 aquilonia:34290         81-5-136-18.dsl.ecl:ntp ESTABLISHED 2504/ntpd
```

Notice the client address?

Comment: How do you believe you can configure OpenNTPd to use unprivileged ports?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to configure OpenNTPD for unprivileged ports? Is it the default configuration?

Comment: Did you really remove the answered flag? What happened when you tried openntpd? I am really curious to hear what did not work.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I do not "believe" that openntpd can be configured to use an unprivileged port. This is not an issue of faith.  I know openntpd works this way. I have updated my answer.